# python + run complicated shell command via python script

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

We want to run the following shell command by python script ( we use python version 2.7 )

```
echo hadoop-hdfs-namenode - 2.6.4.0-91| grep hadoop-hdfs-namenode | awk '{print $NF}' | awk '{printf "%.1f\n", $NF}'
2.6
```

So I create the following python script to get the results - `2.6`

```
import os

os.system("echo hadoop-hdfs-namenode - 2.6.4.0-91| grep hadoop-hdfs-namenode | awk '{print $NF}' | awk '{printf "%.1f\n", $NF}' ")
```

but when I run it we get

```
 os.system("echo hadoop-hdfs-namenode - 2.6.4.0-91| grep hadoop-hdfs-namenode | awk '{print $NF}' | awk '{printf "%.1f\n", $NF}' ")
                                                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is it possible to run this complicated shell via python  ? , in order to get the expected results - `2.6`

And how to fix my syntax?

Comment: You could also use the newer [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) that is intended to replace `os.system` calls.

Comment: in addition to what @mabergerx said its always a good idea to check return codes from each step so you know when an error happens

Comment: change `{printf "%.1f\n", $NF}` to `{printf '%.1f\n', $NF}`

Comment: I get this after the update per you recommendation - awk: cmd. line:1: {printf %.1f
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf %.1f
awk: cmd. line:1:             ^ unexpected newline or end of string
sh: line 1: , $NF}: command not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

escape `"` and `\n` : `os.system("echo hadoop-hdfs-namenode - 2.6.4.0-91| grep hadoop-hdfs-namenode | awk '{print $NF}' | awk '{printf \" %.1f\\n \", $NF}' ")` .

As a side note `os.system` will execute the command (a string) in a subshell and return the return code of the command , if you need the output take a look at the subprocess module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: I get this error - awk: cmd. line:1: {printf "%.1f
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ unterminated string
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf "%.1f
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error

Comment: Be careful you need to escape :  `os.system("echo hadoop-hdfs-namenode - 2.6.4.0-91| grep hadoop-hdfs-namenode | awk '{print $NF}' | awk '{printf \" %.1f\\n \", $NF}' ")`